# ng-pattern doesn't show $error.pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-forms

I have script [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PeUIyf42F7eRq83JgWWx?p=preview) and ng-pattern works correctly because scope.subnet is shown in Output only after input matches pattern. But ng-show doesn't display any error if ng-pattern is not matched

```
<body ng-contoller="myConfigGenCtr">
  <form novalidate name="myForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="hostname">Firewall hostname</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="hostname" class="form-control" id="hostname">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subnet">Firewall subnet</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="subnet" class="form-control" id="subnet"
                       required ng-pattern="/^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}/" >
                <div class="custom-error"  ng-show="myForm.subnet.$error.pattern">
                    Not a valid subnet, should be i.e. 10.x.y. (3 bytes only)</div>
            </div>
        </form>
  <div>Output: {{subnet}}</div>      
</body>
```

Comment: what pattern should match? could you give some example?

Comment: i.e. 1.1.1. it displays fine. But if i type 1.1 error doesnt show up

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you add form tag with its name, angular does create a `scope` variable for that `name` attribute value & do add all the form fields of the form which have `name` attributes. Those fields attribute variable get created inside form scope object. Like here you are using `myForm` that means `$scope.myFrom` has all the information about the form fields. like its validity using `$valid`, `$invalid`, `$error`, etc.

Here you are using `ng-show="myForm.subnet.$error.pattern"` on `subnet` element of form. You missed to add `name="subnet"` attribute on input field, that turns out to `subnet` element validation doesn't available inside `myForm` scope variable.

**Markup**

```
<input type="text" name="subnet" ng-model="subnet" class="form-control" 
id="subnet" required ng-pattern="/^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}/" >
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/UUBwPpmO6Qilc7aMiJEz?p=preview)

Comment: Very nice and simple answer, thanks @Pankaj, I was missing calling it on the pattern attr. Didn't know you could do this.

Comment: @alphapilgrim glad to hear that it helped you. Thanks & cheers ;)

Comment: @ShubhamTiwari you could use `[attr.pattern]="/^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}/"`